# Vim: Do you really use the registers?

Tags: vim

To me, the cognitive process of having to explicitly store and retrieve values from the named registers in `Vim` still feels like a burden after 3 years and a couple of Vim books. I know it has potential, but the process of storing and retrieving breaks my flow and hurts my brain.

Take for example **pasting**:
In `Emacs`, the user simply spams the paste button to cycle through the kill ring. While arguably "dumb", I still like it. It's fluid, requires no planning and minimal thinking.

In `Vim`, the user first-hand has to store said value into a named register, and there are plenty to choose from. Which one do you choose? Either you simply use 1-3 "favorite" registers and stick everything into them, which is still to some degree "dumb". If not, you have to choose a named register based on the value you are storing, or some other way of being able to remember/associate the value for later retrieval.

**This** is the process that I simply cannot get used to. Whenever I have to yank multiple values before pasting the first, I always come to a halt and lose focus of what I am *really* doing (*And that is not to mention the horrendous keybinds to work with the registers, but that's a different story all-together)*.

Am I simply not smart enough to handle `Vim`? I am aware of the `YankStack` plugin, but I do not want to imitate `Emacs` unless there is no other way. How do you go about this?

Comment: "How do you effectively use registers in vi?" maybe?  Given a CPU with a bunch or "registers" and being told - "go make a serial port" is daunting to say the least - Here's a bunch of 'data sheets' - design a UART!  When vi was state-of-the-art (for its vi(suallness) - wish I had some old Sun Microsystems vi tutorials - some knew about RPN in HP calculators to accomplish things differently than on infix brands.  So, "yes" - this could be discussion of opinion over paradigm, or one that facilitates paradigm familiarity.  Of course, the old proverb says, "Once a TI calculator person...."  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The thing about vi is that I never have to take my eyes off the screen.  I'll say that again in a different way - It is like Spock's "mind meld" from TOS ("The Original Series") - I am in connection with the intent of my buffer edit, and my fingers are on the control keys to the kingdom.  In fact, they (my fingers) are just a *lower level protocol* that I seldom worry about...

Here is my typical mental process.

I need this chunk of data, and typically, I think of a chunk of data as a bunch of lines.  So first off, my mind is 95% thinking in terms of a range of lines.  The other 5% of the time, I'll cut a word or two into the yank (inferred) buffer to put somewhere else on the same line - just to move a word or letter around - typically.  I've even dabbled with yanking to the command line, but I don't use that enough to remember it.

So, dealing with the 95% case - the range of lines case - for me personally, I've come up with...

I want these lines, from "b"(eginning) to "e"(nd) - so I'll mark the beginning of a range of lines with the mark "b" and the end with "e", and I either delete into registers starting in ForTran'ly contrived register ranges, but typically, I'll use like, "I'm grabbing stuff into registers, "a", "b", "c", etc. (or "i", "j", "k", ..., or "u", "v", "w", ...) and will eventually paste those registers in somewhere else.  Instead of from "b" to "e", I'll chose from "a" to "z".  But anyway, in my automatic way of marking things (almost disconnected from my brain) - I'll set the range - or use the predefined ranges, like "%", and auto-snag into a range of registers.

Then - I'll just go to where I want to start pasting, and start yanking out of register buffers - and start with "a", then "b", then "c" - until I run out of things to paste.  Or, "depending on whether I had pizza last night", I'll use some other ad hoc "convention" that works for me at the time...

The key is, the registers are accessed in as brief a method as possible - a single letter used in an inferred  key sequence placement with that register name, a single character.

**And my answer is - I use registers in vi all the time.**  In fact, when I'm not adding content, I'm typically interacting with a register in one way, shape, or form.  Registers are good.  To me, they are much better than searching through a window of potential paste buffer content.  Because with vi, if I get it wrong, it's a single "u", and they try another of my conventional buffer letters - until I get the right one.  This latter case is usually the isolated case - I usually get the buffer letter name right.

Have fun with vi.  Vi, especially with the ability to interact with environment filters (some of my favorite being sort, fmt, and grep) - hey, now there's a thought - I usually specify a range of lines for my external filter to process.  I wonder if I can process a buffer through a filter into another buffer?  Then paste the filtered buffer content where I need it.  Something to think about as I use vi the next time - like about in the next minute or so...  I even Vi(per) up my sessions in XEmacs.  :-)  Sick, to most, but I saw this funny graph yesterday that seems so apropos - ah - UNIX poetry:

[image: Classical Learning Curves For Some Common Editors]

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use named registers consciously for yanking/putting but other registers like `"0`, which contains the last yank, `"+` which contains what's in the system's clipboard or `"=`, the expression register are important parts of my workflow.

I tend to reserve named registers for macros which I use a lot.

And I use a system-wide clipboard manager for accessing older clipboard content in Vim *and elsewhere.*

Answer (score 0):

I use registers. I usually use 'a' for storing text. If I am getting complicated[1] and have several things to remember I either use sequential letters, or mnemonic letters - depending upon how long I estimate I'll need to remember their meanings.

`:registers` also comes in handy.

[1] ...and I try not to get complicated.